# Is T an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A is the standard matrix of a linear transformation T. If det(A)=-5, is T an isomorphism?

(Hint: First consider the connection between the determinant of A on one hand, and whether or not A is an invertible matrix on the other hand.)

Comment: It depends on you base field. This is missing a lot of context.

Comment: uhm ok i am sorry will add more next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should follow by the invertible matrix theorem.

Comment: that you so much for the feedback...... :D